# For accessibility, will the 'title' attribute act an identifier for an anchor link which has background images , when the css is disabled?

Tags: anchor, background-image, accessibility, title, css-sprites

say,

```
<a href="#somelink" id="someID" onclick="searchValue();" class="someClass" title="My Search">
</a>


<style>
someClass{
  background: url("someimage.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  height: 27px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 27px;
}
</style>
```

---

when the CSS is disabled will the page still show the title ? if not what is the work around for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

No the `title` will not show, at all when CSS is disabled. Some assistive technology does not read, or give the user access in some cases. In short, do not use `title`.

The proper way is:

```
<a href=".."><img src="image" alt="Search"></a>
```

This will still work even with CSS is off. If the image fails to load for whatever reason, it will say search still - like what you were aiming  for.

Per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890278/for-accessibility-will-the-title-attribute-act-an-identifier-for-an-anchor-li#comment21028865_14895629), if you are wanting to provide more context to a part of the page, instead of:

```
 <div title="Some instructions  here">.......</div>
```

You should do:

```
<div aria-describedby="instID">
<p class="hidden" id="instID>Some instructions</p>
  .... 
</div>
```

where `.hidden` is:

```
.hidden {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: -999px;
}
```

Comment: +1 and with or without CSS, the link would be empty. Bad for accessibility and SEO. Relevant WCAG 2.0 Technique is [Providing link text that describes the purpose of a link for anchor elements - H30](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H30.html)

Comment: Thanks Ryan, one more doubt I have , what if the element is a DIV and is not a link ...  how to get it identified when the CSS is disabled in terms of accessibility ... 'title' attribute will again fail to display with CSS disabled.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "... how to get it identified when the CSS is disabled in terms of accessibility", can you edit your original question? The `title` will never show. There is a firefox add-on, I believe, that makes it show, but I doubt it is accessible.

Comment: Say for a div , if it has a title to it , now if the css is disabled,  when  we test for accessibility as per 508 guidelines , how will the screen reader identify the div element for differently abled users.